# what are the three parameters of mysql_connect for plesk panel?

Tags: mysql, hosting, plesk

I have registered a domain using some web hosting website and I logged into parallels plesk panel,I have uploaded my pages onto it but unable to connect to database does anyone know  what would be three parameters would be?

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

what are the 3 fields i should fill in to connect to mysql on plesk panel, I registered domain just yesterday i am kinda new to this stuff.please help me, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the `mysql host,username,password.`

1. the host will be your ip or localhost(default)
2. your mysql username
3. your mysql password

[mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: how do i get mysqlusername and mysqlpassword?

Comment: when you are creating a database in the mysql you have to provide a username and password

Answer (score 0):

At its basic level any database connection needs location (host), username, and password.  I would assume it would be all three of those, though I don't have plesk panel experience.

Comment: yes but how do i know th mysqlusername and mysqlpassword? is there any way to find out?

Comment: You would either need to consult your install documentation or chat with an admin of your network.  I am not a plesk person at all unfortunately.  Sorry.